# Setting variable from async method

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, global-variables, async-await

Anyone can explain me why can't I set the value of a global variable with an async method? This is my code:

```
public static string sGlobalVar = "";

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _AsyncCallMethod("string");
        MessageBox.Show(sGlobalVar);
    }

    public void _AsyncCallMethod(string sString)
    {
        _InetReadEx(sString);
    }


    public async void _myAsyncMethod(string sString)
    {
        try
        {
            //Do some magic coding here
            sGlobalVar = "Test text";
            //sGlobalVar value is not set after here
        }
        catch (Exception hre)
        {
            sGlobalVar = string.Empty;
        }
```

It is the same sample but here the question is; how to set the value of a global variable via an async method.

Anyway I have found the solution. I could write the solution if you want to re-open the post.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see a code where you invoke `myAsyncMethod` . Can that be the reason :)

Comment: @EZI What do you mean? Please lend me hand here... I am lost

Comment: Please show a complete piece of code and explain exactly what goes wrong.  Does it not compile?  Does it crash when run?  Does it run but not behave as you expect?

Comment: If your `MessageBox.Show` shows blank and  you're expecting it to be "Test test" -- it is because you didn't `await` the call, it will return immediately resulting in showing you the blank.  Not sure if you `_AsyncCallMethod(string sString)` is even needed.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware how can I await the call from the public MainPge(). That would require MainPage() to be async which is not possible...